# TeXnicCenter problem, can't find input index file

Tags: indexing, input, texniccenter

I've just installed TeXnicCenter. The first error I have encountered is that when I try and build I get the following error:

`Couldn't find input index file D:\File location\test nor D:\File location\test.idx.`

Where test is what I have named my document.

Does anyone know what's going on and how to solve this?

Answer (score 5):

TeXnicCenter can start `makeindex` for you but you have to config it. There are two possibilitys for your message:

1. Your document needs no index but TeXnicCenter trys to build it (so there is no index file `idx` for `makeindex`).
2. You want an index in your document. You have no `\makeindex` in your `tex` file. Or TeXnicCenter needs some configuration. Press Alt+F7, click on `LaTeX` and  give Makeindex the right arguments: `"%tm" -s myIndex.ist`. `myIndex.ist` contains your configuration style for `makeindex`.